# Show that S can have at most one object (Herstein Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Having trouble understanding the first problem (I'm new to abstract algebra):

---

1. Let $S$ be a set having an operation * which assigns an element $a * b$ of $S$
   for any $a, b \in S$. Let us assume that the following two rules hold:

   If $a, b$ are any objects in $S$, then $a * b = a$.

   If $a, b$ are any objects in $S$, then $a * b = b * a$.

Show that $S$ can have at most one object.

---

My understanding is that the set $S$ consists of $a$, $b$ and $a*b$. As $a*b=a$, this is sufficient to say that $S$ consists of only $a$ and $b$ (*). Am I supposed to somehow show that $a=b$, and if so, how is this done?

(*) Actually, I don't know why this statement is necessarily true either.

Answer (score 3):

take two elements $a$ and $b\in S$. We have the following equalities due to the hypotheses:

$a=a*b=b*a=b$. So $a=b$, since $a$ and $b$ where arbitrary we conclude $S$ has at most one element.